# Duplicate data in array after user logins again Firebase observe method

Tags: database, duplicates, firebase-realtime-database, observers

Everything works fine until user logs out and logs back again. Seems like Firebase observe method is called twice. I tried to `removeAllObservers` in `viewDidDisssaper` and to removeObserver with handle but it did not help. I still get the duplicate data. What else I can try? Maybe my query is wrong? But then it would show the wrong results in the beginning..

Here is what I am using:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Recent")

func observeRecent() {
        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "sender_id").queryEqual(toValue: senderId()).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            Chats_VC.activeConversations.removeAll()
            for snap in snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] ?? [:] {
                let data = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Recent").child(snap.key)
                data.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] ?? [:]
                    let activeSnapshot = Recent()
                    //....
                    Chats_VC.activeConversations.append(activeSnapshot)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        })
      }
```

Comment: @Hibernia seems to have a similar problem to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699325/firebase-observer-code-running-twice-after-leaving-view

Like I comment there, I don't know if this can help you, but I suffered that duplication and it was beacuse of  `.value`. With a listener, it's called at the beginning, and then everytime I added some data, again...

Comment: Well I need that .value because I am observing for last message in conversation.

Comment: If you want to retrieve only the data on each new request added, try `child_added` instead of `value`.

Comment: To be more specific I don't create new child to observe the data with .childAdded. I only change values.

Comment: Ok... have you tried `.childChanged`?

Comment: Yes. Did not even triggers anything because .childChanged fires when a child node at a location changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find any relative answer. So I just check array for duplication and remove any duplicates