# Firebase observer code running twice after leaving view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got the following observer:

```
currentUserRef.child("invitedToPosts").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: cutoff).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

let postKey = snapshot.key
postsReference.child(postKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
      if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>{
             //creating posts

      }
}
```

I'm in a situation where this code was working a week ago and now it's not, and I don't know where to begin on debugging it.

I've got that observer in my viewDidAppear. When this code runs on startup the posts are created correctly in my view. However, when I leave the view and come back the code where I'm creating posts gets run twice.

I've tried removingAllObservers on the references, but I'm not feeling like thats the issue because the code wasn't doing this before and I was not removing the observers then either.

When I fully clear out my firebase database and make a single post, the data for a post is being posted only once, but when I'm reading it back from firebase it's running the code for the same UID twice.

Anyone had any issues like this before?

Comment: Very strange that situation that a week ago was working and now, not...
I had a similar problem, and, in my case, that was because of  `.value` . It is triggered at the beginning once and then, when everytime you add data, so there was my duplication...

Comment: You just deleted your post of today that seems to be about the same problem. Does that mean this problem has also been solved?

Comment: I found the problem to be my viewDidAppear is getting called twice, has nothing to do with Firebase. I thought it was. Thanks for the help/ time.